# Hibernate Mapping exception related with foreign key

Tags: hibernate, exception, mapping, foreign-key-relationship

I have a problem with my Hibernate Mapping. I have three files, each one of them is the mapping of a hibernate class:

- Proyectos.hbm.xml: Proyectos class
- UnidadesEmpresa.hbm.xml: UnidadesEmpresa class
- CliUniEmps.hbm.xml; CliUniEmp class

I have a problem related with the last one. Its code is this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.dmsti.dominio.CliUniEmp" table="clientes_uniemps"  lazy="false" catalog="dms_hrm">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="cliente" entity-name="com.dmsti.dominio.Cliente"
        column="cliente_id" unique="false" not-null="false" />

        <many-to-one name="unidadEmpresa" entity-name="com.dmsti.dominio.UnidadEmpresa"
        column="uniemp_id" unique="false" not-null="false" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

All the files are properly related by **hibernate.cfg.xml** and all of them usually work. Now let me explain my current problem deeply.

In my Hibernate file **Proyectos.hbm.xml** I have a reference to an entity called **cliUniEmp** which is defined bellow, in CliUniEmps.hbm.xml (and whose table is clientes_uniemps).

**Code 1.**

```
 <many-to-one name="cliUniEmp" entity-name="com.dmsti.dominio.CliUniEmp"
     column="cli_uniemp_id"  unique="false" not-null="false" />
```

In **UnidadesEmpresa.hbm.xml** there is another reference to the same table.

**Code 2.**

```
 <set name="clientes" table="clientes_uniemps"   catalog="dms_hrm"
         inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
        <key>
            <column name="uniemp_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.dmsti.dominio.Cliente">
            <column name="cliente_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
         </set>
```

Both codes work properly when just one of them exists. If I remove the set "clientes" (code 2) from  **UnidadesEmpresa.hbm.xml** then the *many-to-one* entity "cliUniEmp" (code 1) works without any problem. In the same way, if I remove code 1 then code 2 works perfectly.

If both are at the same time in my application, Hibernate launches an exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FKE442A80E4FB5975E:proyectos [cli_uniemp_id])) must have same number
>   of columns as the referenced primary key (clientes_uniemps
>   [uniemp_id,cliente_id])

I became stuck! Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a table naming collision on `clientes_uniemps`.

Think about your object model this way: three entities `CliUniEmp`, `Proyecto`, and `UnidadesEmpresa`.  Each of these three should have their own tables.  Then there's relationships between them: `CliUniEmp` N<->N `UnidadedEmpresa`, `CliUniEmp` 1<->N `Proyecto`.

Both of these relationships need a way to maps the IDs of one entity to IDs of the other.  For the 1<->N relationship, the `Proyecto` table can contain the ID of the `CliUniEmp` directly, which is fine.

For N<->N, you cannot do that.  There has to be an intervening table that contains *pairs* of IDs.  The `table` attribute in your `set` element in `UnidadesEmpresa.hbm.xml` defines the name of that table.  You can read about this in the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional), where they say:

> You also have to describe the association table and the join
>   conditions using the @JoinTable annotation.

The specific problem in your case is that you have used the *same table name* for both the `CliUniEmp` entity **and** the relationship table.  They have to be different.  Change either the name of the association table, or the entity table, and you will be fine.